# Create table with COUNT ms-access

Tags: ms-access, count, percentage, create-table, alter

I have a database and I want to create a table with COUNT function in it. Is it possible ?

I have 3 existing tables:

```
Member
Feedback
Attendance
```

In Feedback table, 2 columns

```
Class_ID, 
Likes
```

(Class_ID link with the attendance, as each member attend 1 class eg. class 1,2,3,etc. and Likes is for the number of people like the class).

In Attendance table, 3 columns:

```
Class_ID
Member_ID
Non_member_name
```

Now I want to alter Feedback table to add 2 new columns. One to count the number of people attend the class, e.g if there is 4 people attend class 1,there would be 4 rows of Class_ID=1. Two to count the percentage of likes i.e Likes/Number_attending*100%

```
ALTER TABLE Feedback
ADD COUNT(*) AS Number_Attending
WHERE Class_ID.Feedback=Class_ID.Attendance
```

I tried to run but there is a syntax error in field definition at the bracket ( before the *. Suggestions/Corrections are welcomed.

Comment: That will never work. Which version of MS Access are you using? 2010 or earlier? 2010 has an option for calculated columns. Storing calculated data is against the rules of normalization and should not be done unless it is essential.

Comment: I m using 2010. I think it is essential as the idea of calculate the number of people attending by manual counting is not very appreciated..

Comment: You do not store the information, you obtain it from a query, so it should not be essential.

Comment: Because my question states: the center want to store the information on a percentage level i.e the number should be include in the table,not a report.

Comment: You may wish to read http://r937.com/relational.html

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
 SELECT Class_ID, Count(Member_ID) As MemCount, Count(Non_Member_Name) As NonMemCount
 FROM Attendances
 GROUP BY Class_ID
```

See alternatively [Access 2010 calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945943.aspx)

Comment: Voted up, you may want to include an AS clause so it doesn't show 'Expr317' though; Count(Member_ID) AS 'Column Name', Count(Non_Member_Name) AS 'Column Name'